# Why doesn't Redis Pub / Sub allow access to Redis within the Callback?

Tags: redis, servicestack, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I am really stuck on this question regarding how to use Redis Pub / Sub (from ServiceStack, but I don't think it is just ServicStack).  I don't see the usefulness of Pub / Sub with this limitation, as we are usually using Redis not just as a message queue.  So if you can't do any Redis commands from a subscription callback, you just end up making your own message handler instead of using Pub / Sub, don't you?

In short, my question is how to properly use Pub / Sub such that you can access Redis when a message comes in?  If there is no way, then Pub / Sub can't be used for many applications.  - I am not posting code because I already know the code to create a Pub / Sub connection.  I am looking for software pattern / architectural advice and affirmation that this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) describes how Pub/Sub is implemented in Redis.

When a Redis client becomes a subscriber it enters into "Listening Mode" where it's effectively waiting for messages published by other clients. The only valid operations the "subscribed" client can perform whilst in this mode is to either Subscribe or Unsubscribe to more channels. When the subscriber unsubscribes from all channels then the client automatically leaves subscriber mode and goes back to operating as a normal client.

So whilst the subscribed client (and connection) cannot be used for anything else, there's nothing to stop you from using a different client to talk to Redis within the message callback.

Comment: So from a design pattern perspective, the issue in my case is that I have a process that has state, that I'm trying to wake up periodically.  I think the case you are mentioning is one where there is no state, so you can use RedisMQ or call any route to take an action.  I can be more specific:  I have several threads running and waiting for the same piece of data.  This lends itself directly to a subscription, as it is a one to many connection.  But the threads maintain state, so when the subscription fires I will have to use Enqueue/Dequeue for example, that is specific to each thread  Clear?

Comment: Another way to say it is that I need another mechanism to wake up a waiting thread that has state, so that it is not part of the message callback.  I can use any C# type of semaphore or other mechanism, I just can't directly use the callback alone.